# Determining the minimum pull force of a magnet required to hold it in place

Tags: electromagnetism

If I place a magnet on the underside of a metal object so that it is held there by its attraction to the metal, how can I determine the minimum pull force the magnet needs to have in order to keep it attracted to the metal and not fall off? Would the required pull force be equivalent to the magnet's weight?

Comment: In short: yes, quite simply that.

Answer (score 1):

What makes a magnet attract to a surface?  What makes a magnet *strongly* attract to a surface at a given field energy?  Look at the pole structure of a refrigerator magnet, then "divergence" of a field.  A simple Fe-Nd-B N45 magnet will pull hundreds of times its weight.  But wait!

http://images.tutorvista.com/cms/images/38/magnetic-materials-list.jpg 
Composition matters 
https://www.ameslab.gov/files/graphMagnets.png 
a lot. 
http://www.kjmagnetics.com/images/blog/fridgemagnet.greenfilm.jpg 
Refrigerator magnet poles 
http://www.kjmagnetics.com/images/blog/halbachvsalt.png 
You can do better.

Answer (score 0):

It is magnetic field strength determine the suspension of magnet underside of metal.to get it suspended,the magnetic force should be greater than or equal to the weight of the magnet itself.